# Need indexing algorithm for ontology models

Tags: indexing, semantic-web, ontology

I am building an semantic web crawler which stores url and ontology models (Triples) but I need an indexing algorithm to store the same

like a page www.abc.com
my crawler extracts

Links

```
www.abc1.com
www.abc2.com
www.abc3.com
```

Model

```
www.abc.com#harry
www.abc.com#friend
www.abc.com#himanshu
```

Answer (score 0):

allegrograph is an indexing tool  for indexing rdf documents

also SPARQL can be used for storing and retrieving RDF files just like dbms does for normal files